# Can't echo laravel 'created_at' timestamp value, displays Jan 1, 1970 instead

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, timestamp

Each laravel migration comes with a built in 'created_at' timestamp column that is automatically populated with your request. When trying to access this value, i am instead provided a '01/01/1970' value. Can someone help with this? I have installed Carbon and followed advice of similar problems to no positive effect.

```
<h3>Date Created:</h3>
    <p>{{ date('d/m/Y', $project['created_at']) }}</p>
```

Targeting the variable like

```
$project->created_at
```

instead produces the same result.

Comment: date accepts a unix timestamp as a second argument, laravel does not use unix timestamps in the db

Comment: `date("format", strtotime($project->created_at));` should work, but it should already be a `Carbon` variable, so `->format("format")` is a better approach.

Comment: This still returned 1/1/1970 hmmmm

Comment: if your `$project['created_at']` is not set, then date will treat this as 0, which is unix timestamp for 1 january 1970. Verify that `created_at` is getting set. This should happen automatically if Eloquent is creating the model, but if you created it via an insert it will not.

Comment: What's the date in the database? can you do DB::table('project')->select('created_at')->where('id', id)->get() ? That way we can see what you have in the database. of if you have phpmyadmin take a look there

Answer (score 1):

Use `format()` instead:

```
{{ $project->created_at->format('d/m/Y') }}
```

Comment: Now i get this error: 

Call to a member function format() on null .../resources/views/confirm.blade.php)

Comment: @MichaelTrieb it means `created_at` property is `null`, so you might want to check the data in the DB. If the timestamp is there, make sure you're not using any accessor, you didn't override the `$dates` property in the model and you're using proper column type for `created_at`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that he has the value of created_at set to null in the database..

Answer (score 1):

Laravel casts date field to Carbon objects by default.

According to the Carbon documentation, you can get the timestamp by using the appropriate getter. In this case it should be:

```
$project->created_at->timestamp
```

Comment: Am now receiving the error 'Trying to get property of non-object'

Comment: Are you sure that `created_at` is not empty?

Comment: timestmap OR timestamp? [sp]

Comment: $project->created_at->timestamp ?? null in php7.1 will give null when created_at is null